# R categorical variable in Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to fit a  Linear Regression in R to a categorical variable that have 3 levels. In particular, my data is the following:

```
Y = 1, X= "Type 1", A=0.5

Y = 2, X= "Type 2", A=0.3

Y =0.5,X= "Type 3", A=2
```

Do I simply do the following:

`lm(Y~ X+ A)` ?

Comment: I would suggest introducing 3 dummy variables (for each type 0-1). Or if they are nominal you can model them as 1,2,3.

Comment: Yes, `lm(Y ~ X + A)` will work fine. If `X` isn't already a factor but is a vector of strings, `lm` will treat it as a factor, using the first value as the reference category and including a dummy variable for each other level in the model. And if `X` is a factor, fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert X into factor and then use lm(Y ~ X + A).Or you can use dummyvars from the caret package -

```
dummy_train<-dummyVars(" ~ .",data=<insert_data_name>)
dummy_train<-data.frame(predict(dummy_train,newdata=<insert_the_same_data_name>))
```

You can run a regression on this.